# Question 3.1.2 in Allen Hatcher, Algebraic Topology(comparing multiplication by n map in $H$ and $G$).

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology, algebraic-k-theory

Here is the question I am trying to understand its solution:

Show that the maps $G \xrightarrow{n} G$ and $H \xrightarrow{n} H$ multiplying each element by the integer $n$ induce multiplication by $n$ in $\operatorname{Ext}(H,G).$

Here is the solution I found online:

> [image]
> [image]

My questions are:

1- In the line after the first diagram, what is the value of $\operatorname{im}f_{1}^{*}$? why the author said that the multiplication by $n$ in $G$ induces multiplication by $n$ in $\operatorname{Hom}(F_1, G)$ only, why he did not speak about the denominator,  $\operatorname{im}f_1^{*}$?

2- Why in the first diagram the induced $n^{*}$ is pointing downwards while in the third diagram the induced $n^*$ is pointing upwards?

3- What about the induced map between $\operatorname{Hom}(F_0, G)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(F, G)$ in the first diagram?

Can someone clarify this to me please?

Comment: This is more complicated than necessary. All you have to show is that $\text{Ext}$ is an additive functor in both variables, then use the fact that $n = 1 + 1 + 1 \dots $.

Comment: I do not understand you and I prefer to understand the details I am asking about .... Would you mind helping me in this please?@QiaochuYuan

Comment: If $A$ is an abelian group, $B$ a subgroup and $f\colon A\to A$ an endomorphism such that $f(B)\subset B$, then the induced endomorphism $\bar{f}\colon A/B\to A/B$ is given by $\bar{f}(a+B)=f(a)+B$. It follows that if $f$ is multiplication by $n$, then the induced map on the quotient group is also multiplication by $n$.